# Calculate Leap Year in Java is bypassing an else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, return, boolean, leap-year

There must be a bug somewhere in my 30 lines of code but I cannot find it and it's driving me nuts.

If I execute this code using `isLeapYear(2004)` I receive a `true`:

```
public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isLeapYear(2004);
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear (int year) {
        boolean status = true;

        if (year >= 0 || year <= 9999) {
            if (year % 4 == 0){
                status = true;
                System.out.println("true");
            } else if (year % 100 == 0){
                status = true;
                System.out.println("true");
            } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
                status = true;
                System.out.println("true");
            } else {
                status = false;
                System.out.println("false");
            }

        } else if (year < 0 || year > 9999){
            status = false;
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

But if I run it for `isLeapYear(-1200)` it returns me a `true` as well but it shouldn't.

Why is my code bypassing `else if (year < 0 || year > 9999)` ?

Comment: Make the first `||` an `&&`   -1200 is smaller than 9999

Comment: Because -1200 is less than 9999, change to &&

Comment: The logic is flawed in multiple places, since the first inner `if` also catches all the other cases. The rules don't seem to be correct, IIRC.  %100 should be false except for %400?!

Comment: The code will never reach either of the  else if statements. If the year is divisible by 100 or 400, it is also divisible by 4. You can also replace the print statements with printing `status` once, after it leaves the if/else.

Comment: You should really learn how to use a debugger - that would have helped you find the problem immediately.

Comment: Thank you guys, is my first week at Java, I'm learning.
Any code suggestion is welcome BTW.

Comment: Thank you @Dejke, how to print the status once?

Comment: @Francesco Dejke means to remove the `System.out.println` `tue|false` and write `System.out.println(status)` *once* above`return status;`

Comment: You conditions should be placed in reverse order. Check for year % 400 first, then %100, then %4. I think there is still another condition you need to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to change your first if statement to :

`if (year >= 0 && year <= 9999) {`

-1200 was always lower than 9999 so it was always going through this condition because of the `||`.